# How does one square an array of numbers using a FOR OF loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I am trying to square an array of numbers so that each number prints out the number multiplied by itself.

ex:

```
const numbers = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for (let numb of numbers) {
numb * numb;

console.log(numb)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am doing Colt Steele's web developer boot camp on Udemy and he doesn't explain his quizzes at all he just throws one at you with little to no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the square of the number but you're not doing anything with it, you either have to store it into a variable or print it directly:

```
for (let numb of numbers) {
    const square = numb * numb;
    console.log(square)
}
```

or:

```
for (let numb of numbers) {
    console.log(numb * numb)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the array and then output it.

```
const numbers = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const squared = numbers.map(num => num * num)

console.log(squared) // Array of squared numbers.
```

Or, you could then loop this and print out one-by-one.

```
for (const square of squared) {
  console.log(square)
}
```